# Array of multiple select inputs

Tags: php, arrays, forms, select

I have this form :

```
<form>
    <select name="data[][]" multiple="multiple">
        <option>1</option>
        <option selected="selected">2</option>
    </select>

    <select name="data[][]" multiple="multiple">
        <option selected="selected">3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>

    <select name="data[][]" multiple="multiple">
        <option selected="selected">5</option>
        <option selected="selected">6</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I would like to get this :

```
$_POST['data'] = array(
    0 => array(2),
    1 => array(3),
    2 => array(5,6)
);
```

I instead get this :

```
$_POST['data'] = array(
    0 => array(2),
    1 => array(3),
    2 => array(5),
    3 => array(6)
);
```

The solution would be to set the index : name="data[0][]" but i want it to be automatically done ..

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you generating the form?

Comment: You can not expect an index to magically appear if you don’t want to set it in the first place … PHP doesn’t “know” that these are three separate select boxes, it only sees the parameters it gets passed – and if those are all named `data[][]`, then you can expect no other result.

Comment: I thought html was smart enough to group each multiple select in a unique index but as you say, it is done in php so i have to manage properly the indexes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way.Change to :

```
<select name="data[0][]" multiple="multiple"> 
 ...
<select name="data[1][]" multiple="multiple">
 ...
<select name="data[2][]" multiple="multiple">
```

Also see  @CBroe comment.

Comment: @Yuukuari why? what is  a problem?

Comment: Because i want to dynamically add these multiple select inputs, in javascript. I build a generic multiple select that is cloned each time i click on a "Add" button. Instead, after what you and CBroe said, i see i have to use a function with the index as a parameter that builds the multiple select input.

Comment: you can dynamically do it. Inc index from starting zero value  (e.g. index++) and set ,on click "Add", name for every new multiple select as `"data["+index+"][]"` by js/jQuery

Comment: That's what i did :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
You don't need to insert the keys manually.
I tested your code and it seems to be correct for what you intend to get or you  expect.
I tested it like this;
<html>
<body>
<?php
if (!isset($_GET["submit"])) {
?>
<form method="get" action="yourfilename.php">
<select name="data[][]" multiple="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option selected="selected">2</option>
</select>

<select name="data[][]" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>

<select name="data[][]" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">5</option>
    <option selected="selected">6</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
}
else {
$data= $_GET["data"];
print_r($data);
echo $show;
}

\\ So to get the 5 or 6 value in the array with key "2";
\\ Output: 5
$show= $data[2][0];

\\ Or
\\ Output: 6
$show= $data[2][1];

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's weird because i tested it again, on Safari, Firefox, Chrome and IE11 and with GET or POST values i get the same result, an array with 4 keys instead of 3, the 5 and 6 values not being grouped together :/

Comment: Yes i get this :
    `Array (
        [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) 
    )`

Comment: What i expect is `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 5 , [1] => 6 ) )` ! But don't worry, my problem was solved above :)

Comment: and that is exactly what i got with my code !  Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 ) )          i used chrome